# Marklogic DataHub Management GUI

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

When you install the quick start Data Hub, it usually installs on port 8080 or 9000 ( which is user configurable )
e.g.  https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-hub-quickstart/

I have installed a 5.2.6 Data Hub on a Server 9.0-13.1 using Gradle project here
( https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/projects/create-project-using-gradle.html )
and then ran the mlDeploy command which appears to have gone OK, its created services etc in the MarkLogic server which I can connect to , so all good.

However I cant find where the GUI interface is for this Gradle deployed data hub, which I would like to use ( i.e. same as the GUI for Quickstart ) - can I set up a GUI to administer a Gradle deployed Data Hub? Or is the Data Hub supposed to be set up/driven using APIs only?

Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data Hub Framework, which is what gets deployed with Gradle, doesn't come with a UI itself. You can do basic MarkLogic administration via the Admin UI, or use the ml-gradle project, and its scaffolding tasks to manage your Data Hub project. You can also download a matching version of QuickStart, spin that up locally, and use that to manage your locally stored Data Hub project. You then either use QuickStart or Gradle to deploy it to your remote environments. Some find it convenient to edit entities, flows and steps through QuickStart, but a straight-forward editor, and the scaffolding tasks can get you there too. More on scaffolding tasks can be found here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/tools/gradle/gradle-tasks.html#gradle-tasks__marklogic-data-hub-scaffolding-tasks

It might also be worth checking out [Envision for Data Hub](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/envision/). It is a community project that aims at low-code configuration of your Data Hub projects.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you, I did wonder if you could use Quickstart effectively as a management GUI.  Can you use Quickstart on one server to manage a remote server? I did notice the new cloud data hub seems to have a GUI, are there any plans to make one for non-cloud systems please?

Comment: @steve Quickstart is intended for development only, and can be used for on-premise or cloud based systems.  The Data Hub Service(DHS) comes with DHF preinstalled and is running with limited permissions since the underlying MarkLogic database is being managed by MarkLogic.  Quickstart can be configured to manage DHF on either local or remote systems to assist in developing code that can then be deployed to DHS using gradle, but can't be used with DHS directly.

Comment: Thanks, I did run up Quickstart and it seems to find everything OK.